# Tomcat application deployment using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

when I tried to deploy my application on tomcat server using eclipse ide, my application not going to webapps folder.
even I tried changing the VM arguments in the run configurations,,but the argument values is keep on changing to its default value/.
the VM argument valued I tried to change is -Dwtp.deploy..even after changing the deplotment path it is still not going to webapps folder.
 '
could you please help me in this regard

Thanks and regards,
abhi

Comment: Please try to format your post so that you show what you tried and what the output was.

Comment: Your description is not enough to diagnose your problem. It is probably a configuration issue, but there are many point where this could fail. e.g. what is the folder structure of you source code? Are your src/build output folder correctly defined? Does you application have the proper facets? Is your IDE properly configured for tomcat? Please add more details to get better help